# How should I handle Laplace smoothing in Naive Bayes in this example?

Tags: naive-bayes, laplace-smoothing

I have a toy dataset on animals, with 4 features and 2 possible classes (`mammals` vs `non-mammals`).

I have summarized the dataset with the count of each instance of the attributes:

[image: counts]

I would like to apply Laplace smoothing with $\alpha=1$

- In the `mammals` class we have seen that all features only had `yes` or `no` as possible value.
- In the `non-mammals` class we have seen that some features had `sometimes` as well as a possible value.

for the example of `give_birth=no`, for $p(\text{give_birth}=\text{no}|\text{class}=\text{non-mammals})$ I would calculate $\frac{12 + \alpha}{(12 + 1) + 3\alpha}$

I am not sure what to do in the case of $p(\text{give_birth}=\text{no}|\text{class}=\text{mammals})$.

Should I assume that `sometimes` is a possible value therefore have $3\alpha$ in the denominator?
Or should I have $2\alpha$ in the denominator instead since we have not seen `sometimes` in the `mammals` instances in the training dataset?

What is the general approach for Laplace smoothing that encompasses all possible missing values/unseen data?

Comment: Please clarify whether the `NaN` entries represent censored data, impossible events, or possible events that were simply not observed.

Comment: I did `df.groupby('class')` then did `value_counts()` for each column then put all of them in a single dataframe.

`NaN` signifies that `sometimes` was not seen in those columns for that specific class, i.e. `give_birth` never had `sometimes` in class `non-mammals`. `sometimes` row only existed there due to some 4 `non-mammals` that had `sometimes` under `live_in_water`. I apologize for the confusion.